# How do I make geom_bar colors change with gganimate when x and y are constant?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I'm new to `gganimate` and was having difficulty figuring out how to do this.

I'd like to show the spread in two different levels of a variable by animating colour transitions. I want to show this by having the `narrow level` transition through a smaller range of colours than the `wider level` in the same amount of time. Is this possible?

Here's the reproducible example I have up-to now.

```r
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = rep(c("narrow", "wide"), each = 1000),
                 y = c(sort(runif(n = 1000, min = 6, max = 7)),
                       sort(runif(n = 1000, min = 3, 10))),
                 animate.time = c(1:1000))

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, fill = y)) + 
  geom_bar()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

As part of this, the color scale that each bar uses should be the same, but the `narrow` x should occupy a narrower range of the color range than the `wide` x.

I used `geom_bar` because I don't want the shape of the visualisation to change, however I'm not sure how to proceed. I tried adding `animate.time` so that `gganimate` would have something to step through, but then I don't see how I'm supposed to make it change colors based on `y`.

I'd appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easier way to do this based on [this](https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/issues/341).

```r
library(colorspace)
library(gganimate)
library(ggplot2)

# Narrow Visualization

narrow<-data.frame(x = rep(10,10),
                      state_cont=rep(1:2, each = 5))

ggplot(data = narrow, aes(x = x, fill = state_cont)) +
  geom_bar() +
  colorspace::scale_fill_continuous_sequential(palette = "Reds 3", begin = 0.4, end = .6) +
  transition_states(states = state_cont) + theme_void() + 
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image: Narrow Colour]

```r
# Wide Visualization
wide <- data.frame(x=rep(10,10),
                       state_cont=rep(1:2, each = 5))

ggplot(data = wide, aes(x = x, fill = state_cont)) +
  geom_bar() +
  colorspace::scale_fill_continuous_sequential(palette = "Reds 3", begin = 0, end = 1) + 
transition_states(states = state_cont) + theme_void() + theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image: Wide Colour]

The explanation is that for this particular question, you don't want to set every single value that it should oscillate through, it'd be much easier to simply set the boundaries in the `scale_fill_continuous_sequential()` via the `begin` and `end` arguments. Then, `gganimate` will automatically cycle through based on `state_cont`